# How can I move box2d object?

Tags: iphone, box2d

I have a player character and I would like him to fire bullets, one each second.

It's a top down view, no gravity.

I've been doing it with SetLinearVelocity() and ApplyLinearImpulse() and the object moves, but I can't control the speed.

How can I control the speed of the bullets?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've already found your answer here: http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5852&p=27016

Comment: from that answer:  
// I don't understand this, but without it, speed is not constant in all directions
direction.Normalize();

it's because otherwise it's not only a direction, but also the distance between the character and the touch point. by normalizing it becomes just the direction.